# If $\{a_n \}$ converges and $\{b_n\}$ diverges, show that $\lim (a_n/b_n) =0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

If $\{a_n \}$ converges and $\{b_n\}$ diverges, show that $\lim (a_n/b_n) =0$.

How do I prove this?

Comment: this is not true. Take $a_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=(-1)^n$. Then $(a_n/b_n)$ diverges.

Comment: I think what you mean is that $(b_n)$ should diverge definitely, i.e. go towards $\pm\infty$. Then, this is indeed true. Did you mean that?

Comment: $b_n$ may be bounded but oscillating. In that case it is not true.

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this problem, I am going to assume that $b_{n}\rightarrow+\infty$.

Since $a_{n}$ converges, it is bounded. That is to say $|a_{n}|\leq M$.

On the other hand, for every $M/\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \geq 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Longrightarrow b_{n} \geq \frac{M}{\varepsilon} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{|b_{n}|} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{M}
\end{align*}

Consequently, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \geq 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Longrightarrow \left|\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} - 0\right| \leq M\times\frac{\varepsilon}{M} = \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Consequently $a_{n}/b_{n}\to 0$, and we are done.